# Xcode 10 iOS OpenCV linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 4.0.1 in my project, but when i try create instance of video camera  videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView]; i'm getting error linker command failed with exit code 1 and can't see full description. If comment videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView]; all it's OK.

Comment: In file Inspector Check for any File name is red if yes then remove it and add it again.

Answer (score 0):

On the left navigation bar, select the top level project file so that you see the "Build Phases" on the right panel. There select the "Link Binary with Libraries." If opencv2.framework is not there, add it. If it is there, remove it and add it again.

This has worked for me with weird framework issues.

link